# Converting GeoJSON FeatureCollection to GeoJSON geometry object

Tags: python, json, geojson

I currently have a GeoJSON `FeatureCollection`, but the function I need to execute on this file in Python only supports GeoJSON geometry objects such as `Point` or `Polygon` (without all of the attribute and coordinate data). Is there a way to simply convert a GeoJSON `FeatureCollection` to a GeoJSON geometry object in Python?

Comment: You can load the GeoJSON FeatureCollection into a dictionary object using json module in python then iterate over the collection to extract each to a separate geometry object.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way would be to loop through your feature collection and extract the geometry from there. I assume you have found the answer to your question by now, since there hasn't been another post since?

Answer (score 0):

To split apart the features of GeoJSON feature collection, need to iterate over the features element and export each feature.

```
for f in data['features']:
    if f.get("type") == "Feature":
        with open(somefile, "w") as out:
            json.dump(f, out)
```

The following Python code will iterate over a GeoJSON feature collection and split each feature saving it in a separate GeoJSON file.

If source GeoJSON file has 10 features then they will be saved in files: 1.geojson, 2.geojson, ..., 10.geojson.

```python
import json
import sys

class Splitter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def check(self, input_file):
        print("Input:", input_file)
        with open(input_file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        data_type = data.get("type")
        if data_type == "FeatureCollection":
            for f in data['features']:
                obj_type = f.get("type")
                if obj_type == "Feature":
                    self.export_feature(data, f)
                else:
                    print("WARN: non-feature:", obj_type)
        elif data_type == "Feature":
            print("GeoJSON is already a feature object")
        else:
            print("WARN: unknown/other type:", data_type)

    def export_feature(self, parent, feature):
        self.count += 1
        name = f"{self.count}.geojson"
        print("Output:", name)
        if "crs" in parent and "crs" not in feature:
            # copy coordinate reference system (CRS) definition from parent
            # if not present in feature
            feature["crs"] = parent["crs"]
        with open(name, "w") as out:
            json.dump(feature, out)

##############################################################################
# main #
##############################################################################

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("usage: geojson-split.py <file>")
    sys.exit(0)

splitter = Splitter()
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    splitter.check(f)
```

If need to split a GeometryCollection into its component geometries then see related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170610/543969).